# What does android:progressTintMode, android:secondaryProgressTintMode and android:progressDrawable do?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I am making a custom ProgressBar. How does `android:progressTintMode` and `android:secondaryProgressTintMode` effect the look of the Progress Bar? 
I looked into the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:progressTint) but couldn't understand.
 Also how does `android:progressDrawable` effect the Progress Bar?

Comment: I can only help you with `progressDrawable`, please take a look at [this tutorial](www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the progressDrawable defines the shape and color of the progress bar, then the progressTintMode defines how the progress bar will fill up.

E.G. if you want to have a progress bar with rounded corners, then the progressDrawable will define the shape with rounded corners. You would then use "src_in" as the progressTintMode so it will only fill up within the shape.

Comment: what about other constants like `src_atop`, `multiple`, `screen` and `add`..?

Comment: This is the page that has the full details. I don't entirely understand what they all do, but src_over and src_in are the most obvious and I would think the ones used most often.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:progressTintMode